# Columns are not displayed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts, live

i'm new on live charts and maybe this is a stupid mistake but for now i don't understand why my columns are not displayed on my charts. i have tried but seems that the binding not work correktly. But if i use biding with serire collection this work weel and my columns are displayed.

this is my xaml code :

````
<lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="ChartICT" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" LegendLocation="Left">

     <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
         <lvc:AxesCollection>
             <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding Labels}" LabelsRotation="15" MinValue="1" MaxValue="{Binding MaxValue}">
                 <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                     <lvc:Separator Step="1" IsEnabled="True"/>
                 </lvc:Axis.Separator>
             </lvc:Axis>
         </lvc:AxesCollection>
     </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
     <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
         <lvc:AxesCollection>
             <lvc:Axis Title="Sold Apps" MinValue="1" MaxValue="95" LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}" ></lvc:Axis>
             
         </lvc:AxesCollection>
     </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
     <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
         <lvc:ColumnSeries Values="{Binding Valuess}" DataLabels="True" Title="Prova" Fill="LightBlue" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Visible"/>
     </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
 </lvc:CartesianChart>

```
````

and this is my c# code:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propname)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}

private string _TitleX;

public string TitleX

{

    get => _TitleX;

    set

    {
        _TitleX = value;

        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TitleX));

    }

}


private int _Step;

public int Step

{

    get => _Step;

    set

    {
        _Step = value;

        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Step));

    }

}

public string[] _Labels;

public string[] Labels

{

    get => _Labels;

    set

    {
        _Labels = value;

        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Labels));

    }

}

public int _MaxValue;

public int MaxValue

{

    get => _MaxValue;

    set

    {
        _MaxValue = value;

        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MaxValue));

    }

}
public LiveCharts.ChartValues<int>[] _Valuess;

public LiveCharts.ChartValues<int>[] Valuess

{

    get => _Valuess;

    set

    {
        _Valuess = value;

        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Valuess));

    }

}

public Func<double, string> Formatter { get; set; }
public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
List<ChartValues<int>> seriesList = new List<ChartValues<int>>();


 public void AddingLabelsX()
 {
     foreach (LoaData.Product product in products_list)
     {
         LoaData.Product product1 = new LoaData.Product();
         product1.Descrizione = product.Descrizione;
         bool alreadyExist = productsDesc_list.Any(v => v == product1.Descrizione);                
         if (!alreadyExist)
         {
             productsDesc_list.Add(product1.Descrizione.ToString());
             
             
         }

     }
     
> `Labels = productsDesc_list.ToArray(); //Labels asseX
> MaxValue = Labels.Length;//Assex
> seriesList.Add(new ChartValues<int> {5,20,50,32,11}); 
> Valuess = seriesList.ToArray();  `          
 }`
```

now what i can do ? thank you everyone.

Comment: this is called row grouping, there is plenty of tutorials regarding that, you shouldnt use a listview for the cell, try this for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8